# Get ACF field data within foreach loop - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom image field for all pages with a specific page template (using ACF plugin).

I'm querying for these pages like so:

```
    $posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'meta_key'      => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value'    => 'services-page.php'
));
```

Then I'm displaying pages with a foreach loop:

```
if( $posts ): ?>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post );?>
//content goes here
<?php endforeach; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I want to access the custom field to display inside the loop. But, below doesn't work. I'm guessing because ACF fields don't get appended to the post object.

```
//Does not work    
$image = $post -> services_block_image
```

ACF has the `get_field()` function, but what can I do to get the field for each of the posts from my original query? Found ACF docs to be rather confusing on this (goes without saying I'm a bit new to PHP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within loop use `get_field` function to get the image.

check below code for your reference.

```
 $image = get_field('services_block_image'); // get the image
 if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is not correct. This is only for while() loop, and not for foreach()